# I have issue with create a dynamic created optionbuttons (radiobuttons), in Excel VBA Forms

Tags: excel, vba, forms, radio-button

I have tried a lot of solution, without success and now need your help. I have reduces my complete code, for easier understanding.

I have a form with tree fixed optionbuttons, belong to Group1. Named OptionButton2 to Optionbutton4. I want to create one dynamic created optionbutton, named OptionButton1, also in Group1. Then select one of button, values should be written i cells. OptionButton2 to OptionButton4 works fine, but not the code-created button. Someone with superbrain, want to help me?
(In final code I will create a loop to create a lot of buttons)

```
Option Explicit
Dim opSel As String

Private Sub UserForm_initialize()
Dim OptionButton1 As Control
Set OptionButton1 = Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "OptionButton1", True)
With OptionButton1
.Name = "OptionButton1"
.Caption = "OptionButton1"
.GroupName = "Group1"
.Value = 0
.Top = 5
.Left = 10
End With
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
  opSel = OptionButton1.GroupName & " " & OptionButton1.Name
    Debug.Print "Selected button: " & opSel
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "TEST-Button1"
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
  opSel = OptionButton2.GroupName & " " & OptionButton2.Name
    Debug.Print "Selected button: " & opSel
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(2, 1).Value = "TEST-Button2"
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
  opSel = OptionButton3.GroupName & " " & OptionButton3.Name
    Debug.Print "Selected button: " & opSel
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(3, 1).Value = "TEST-Button3"
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
  opSel = OptionButton4.GroupName & " " & OptionButton4.Name
    Debug.Print "Selected button: " & opSel
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Cells(4, 1).Value = "TEST-Button4"
End Sub


'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1").Columns("A:A").Clear
'End Sub
```

Comment: When adding controls dynamically the most flexible approach is to use a "control array" - this saves you from having to write handlers for each control you add.  See for example: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Thanx @Tim, Your answer give me a hint how to do and now it works like a glow.

Answer (score 1):

My solution used in a userform 1000 width: I use TAG to catch the value I then want to use later in Class1 module. Edit what to happen in class1 module. In my final solution I will catch and enter values in specific excel cells.

```
'In class1 module:
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.OptionButton
Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()
  Debug.Print Me.CmdEvents.Tag
End Sub

'In form code
Dim cmdArray_1_2() As New Class1
Dim cmdArray_2_1() As New Class1
Dim cmdArray_2_2() As New Class1
Dim cmdArray_3_1() As New Class1
Dim cmdArray_3_2() As New Class1

Dim rng As Range
Dim rcell As Range
Dim Offset
Dim CountRowLoop
Dim topval As String
Dim starttop
Dim offsetcell As String

starttop = 135
topval = 165
offsetcell = 135
CountRowLoop = 1

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
For Each rcell In rng.Cells

'--OptionButtonSection1----------------
Dim optArtStat1 As Control, optArtStat2 As Control
Set optArtStat1 = Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "optArtStat1_" & CountRowLoop, True)
With optArtStat1
    .Name = "optArtStat1_" & CountRowLoop
    .GroupName = "optArtStat" & CountRowLoop
    .Caption = "Option 1_" & CountRowLoop
    .Tag = "TESTING Option:1 Button:1 Row:" & CountRowLoop
    .Left = 610
        If CountRowLoop = 1 Then
            .Top = starttop
        End If
            If CountRowLoop > 1 Then
            .Top = offsetcell
        End If
    End With
ReDim Preserve cmdArray_1_1(1 To CountRowLoop)
Set cmdArray_1_1(CountRowLoop).CmdEvents = optArtStat1
'--OptionButtonSection2----------------
Set optArtStat2 = Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "optArtStat2_" & CountRowLoop, True)
With optArtStat2
    .Name = "optArtStat2_" & CountRowLoop
    .GroupName = "optArtStat" & CountRowLoop
    .Caption = "Option 1_2_" & CountRowLoop
    .Tag = "TESTING Option:1 Button:2 Row:" & CountRowLoop
    .Left = 610
        If CountRowLoop = 1 Then
            .Top = starttop + 15
        End If
            If CountRowLoop > 1 Then
            .Top = offsetcell + 15
        End If
    End With
ReDim Preserve cmdArray_1_2(1 To CountRowLoop)
Set cmdArray_1_2(CountRowLoop).CmdEvents = optArtStat2
```